# Is resolving a promise an asychronous process?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

<strike>I am sure that all the codes below, except `resolve(Promise.resolve(p2))`, are synchronous.</strike>
So I expect the result is `p2` first since the `p2.then` run first. However `p1` comes out first in console.

MDN has nothing related to the question.
Does the spec has some details? Can someone make it clear step by step what happens in resolving a promise?

Chrome v60.0.3112.113

My code is:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  resolve("p1");
});

var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  //resolve("p2");
  var tempP = Promise.resolve("p2"); // for better description in discussion
  resolve(tempP);
});

p2.then(function(value){
  console.log(value)
})
p1.then(function(value){
  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am sure that all the codes below, except `resolve(Promise.resolve(p2))`, are synchronous.

No. `then` callbacks are *never* called synchronously, they're always asynchronous (and that's good). That means their relative order is indeterminate, and depends on when the respective promise was fulfilled. If you ever care about the order of callbacks, make it explicit by chaining the promises onto each other.

The order of fulfillment in your example depends on the value that you resolved the promises with. Notice that the `new Promise` callback and therefore your `resolve` are synchronous, in both `p1` and `p2`. Every resolution is put into a queue - at least with native ES6 promises that you appear to be using. The difference is that your `p2` is resolved with `Promise.resolve("p2")`, which will resolve `p2` with the result of that other promise - which is put back onto the queue again. Therefore the fulfillment of `p1` happens first, and the callback is called before the fulfillment callback of `p2`.

So what happens step-by-step is

1. The `new Promise` calls the constructor callback, which in turn
2. `resolve`s the new promise with the value `"p1"` - fulfilling it
3. The `new Promise` returns and the value is assigned to `p1`.
4. The `new Promise` calls the constructor callback, which in turn
5. constructs another promise fulfilled with the value `"p2"`
6. and `resolve`s the new promise with it - which adds another `resolve` as a callback for when that promise completes
7. The inner promise schedules that callback as it is already is fulfilled
8. The `new Promise` returns and the value is assigned to `p2`.
9. The `p2.then` is called and registers the fulfillment callback
10. The `p1.then` is called and schedules the fulfillment callback, as `p1` is already fulfilled

After that, asynchronously:

1. the inner promise's callback is called and resolves `p2` with the value `"p2` - fulfilling it and scheduling its registered callbacks
2. the `p1` callback is called and logs `"p1"`
3. the `p2` callback is called and logs `"p2"`

Comment: Excuse me, what does it mean by `schedules the fulfillment callback`? Is it the same as `registers the fulfillment callback`?

Comment: *`Using $.when().then()`* - so you're not using Promises then

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.

`Promise.resolve()` returns a promise which is guaranteed to be asynchronous. So the value it returns will always resolve at the earliest on the next event loop after it is called. So in this case what happens is:

P2 returns a promise
P1 returns a promise

**Next loop**

P2 calls `then()` which resolves to a new promise that's scheduled for the *next* loop
P1 calls `then()` callback which resolves to a value which is printed

**Next loop**

P2's returned promise resolves and is printed

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` is not asynchronous at all, it returns immediately?

Comment: Yes @Bergi - I adjusted the answer. Promise.resolve() returns a promise which is guaranteed to be asynchronous. You're right that it's an important distinction.

Comment: I think you mean the right thing by "*P2 calls then() resolves to a new promise*" but it's formulated weirdly

Answer (score -1):

Both p1 and p2 are async, as you are creating a Promise. 
New Promise() creates a new promise, and once it is created the following code is executed, but execution inside the Promise is done later (or at the same time; async).

p2.then is not executed before p1.then. The .then function is executed, once the promise resolves, and p1 resolves before p2

Comment: "*but execution inside the Promise is done later*" - that's wrong or at least mistakable. The `new Promise` callback is synchronous - what happens in there might however be a call to an asynchronous function.

Answer (score -1):

You code above :

```
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(Promise.resolve("p2"));
});
```

Is equivalent to doing :

```
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(new Promise(function(resolve1, reject1) {
        resolve1("p2"); 
    }));
});
```

Which creates a new promise that is although immediately resolved, will be executed at the end of the call queue.

Comment: Excuse me, does the call queue refer to the “task queue” of Event Loop in browser?

Comment: The task queue.